# How to remove file assosiations for particular file types

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux, file-association

How can I remove file associations in Kali Linux. I accidently made my firefox download file with .part extension open with video player as default. I looked in the /etc/xfce4/defaults.list but it is empty. Is there any command to remove file assosiation.

Comment: In my Kali Linux machine here, go to Firefox, Settings, General, scroll down to Applications . Change Firefox associations here.  Does this help?

Comment: @John No. Firefox doesn't include it in the option you said. I useddefault file explorer to change the file association of .part so there should be some way in the system to change it back

Comment: Have you got an old version of Kali / Firefox?  I have Kali 2020.4 and Firefox V78.3

Comment: Thunar (Default File explorer) does not have an associations setting that I can see.  I checked all the Thunar options.

Comment: I have the latest version of both. I too think that thunar doesn't have that option. I wonder if I can access it through the command line or edit the file thunar uses to store such info